# Should I add view.loadUrl(url) in shouldOverrideUrlLoading?

Tags: android, hyperlink, webview

I just do like this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
return false;
}
```

and I get the right result:
When i click a link ,the link opened in my app;
But in the book , like this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
view.loadUrl(url)
return false;
}
```

Should I add view.loadUrl(url)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do *not* override the method at all, all the links will be opened in your WebView.

If you want to open just *some* links in your app, you should do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (doYouWantToOpenItHere(url)) {
        return false; // no need to use loadUrl!
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
        return true; // let me handle this!
    }
}
```

As you can see, in both cases you don't have to use `webview.loadUrl(url)`.

Comment: but in demo, people ofen add webview.loadUrl(url)

Comment: It's nonsense. If you do it, it's just for debug reasons (you may want to track each step the webview does). But in production, there's no need to use it.

Comment: I was having a headache with a page in apsx that had a javascript code with a __doPostBack on a link. Using the view.loadUrl(url) was bringing weird behavior. When I did as you suggested everything worked! Thanks a lot @Gianluca.

Answer (score 0):

No. Just return false if you need load this url or return true if that url must be not loaded. But if you want do work with url and load it after you must add view.loadUrl(changed_url) before return true;

Answer (score 0):

shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) is the method of WebViewClient.
If you want to use your custom WebViewClient then you can add view.loadUrl(url).

Here is an example of custom WebViewClient :

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            if (!pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.show();
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //view.loadUrl(url);
            System.out.println("on finish");
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }
```

You can set this as below :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Comment: if I add view.loadUrl(url)  ,I get 2 onPageStarted and 2 onPageFinished.